# wxPython Disable Frame Resizing

Tags: resize, wxpython, frame

How can I disable a wxFrame from being resized by the user? If there's a flag to put in when creating the frame, what is it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [default window style is](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8.11/wx_wxframe.html#wxframe) 
`wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX | wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CLIP_CHILDREN`

If you remove wx.RESIZE_BORDER from it, you'll get a frame which cannot be resized.

Something like this should do the stuff :

```
wx.Frame(parent, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
```

Comment: Both suggestions did not work for me on Mac OS 10.12.

Comment: It works for me. This is the exact line that I 'm using:                                                                class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=APP_TITLE, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER)

Answer (score 7):

I tried the suggestion above using this program:

```
import wx

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

...but it didn't work. The frame still remains resizable.

Replacing the style value with this "wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & (~wx.RESIZE_BORDER)" didn't work either. The frame was still resizable.

Using SetMaxSize() and SetMinSize() does prevent resizing, but the resize arrows still appear on Mac OS X.

Example:

```
import wx

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, size=(400,300))
frame.SetMaxSize(wx.Size(400,300))
frame.SetMinSize(wx.Size(400,300))
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

3-20-2019 update:
https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Frame.html
According to this page to disable frame resizing use this:

```
style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~(wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX)
```

Using this example program I was able to make the resize arrows completely disappear on Mac OS 10.12:

```
import wx

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~(wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX))
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SetSizeHints (or SetMaxSize and SetMinSize) to restrict the maximum and minimum sizes or th